# How can I integrate ZXing (Zebra crossing) in GWT?

Tags: gwt, zxing, gwt2, gxt

I want to generate barcode using Zxing in GWT application.

I have implemented the code with QRCodeWriter. It works fine. If i run it as a simple java program. Later I integrated the same in my GWT application. While  compiling I am getting error as "**No source code is available for type com.google.zxing.oned.com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter; did you forget to inherit a required module**"

**QRCodeWriter** exists in **Zxing** , **core-2.2.jar** but I could not find any **.gwt.xml** in **core-2.2.jar**

So help me to get rid of this.

**Or this there any other tool/library which is suitable for generating barcode in GWT application**?

Comment: You can use jsni(javascript in gwt) to wrap and use jquery plugins http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html or https://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcode/.

Comment: @Prince, can you tell me, precisely which technologies are you using? GWT, Ext-GWT, SmartGWT or GWT2 or all of them?

Comment: RAS:   Its GWT only..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a module for your Zxing client side I don't think it could work! the classes you want to usqe are probably for serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

GWT client side code gets cross-compiled into Javascript. The Zxing package is pure Java, and cannot be used on the client side unless they explicitly support GWT (they provide you with a module you can inherit).

What you could do is make a servlet that generates barcodes on the server side (server side code doesn't get cross-compiled) and sends the response as an Image.

If Zxing only uses classes that [GWT allows on the client side](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html), you can make a package in your project, put the Zxing source code there, and `<source path='...' />` tag in your `GWT.xml` to make it usable in the client side. But I don't to what extent that would work, and I don't know if their license agreement will permit that.

Answer (score 0):

Zxing cannot be used in client side gwt, but you can use javascript libs.
One of them is http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html.

To use this lib you need to make this steps:

include before your xxx.nocache.js this js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-barcode.js"></script>
```

and use this piece of code to generate your barcode

```
SimplePanel simplePanel = new SimplePanel();
RootPanel.get().add(simplePanel);
createBarcode(simplePanel.getElement(), "1234567890128", "ean13");
```

...

```
private native void createBarcode(Element element, String data, String type) /*-{
    $wnd.$(element).barcode(data, type);
}-*/;
```